# Parsing json.dumps to HighCharts in Django

Tags: django, highcharts

I'm trying to create a pie chart with HighCharts with Django (Mac maverick).

```
This is my views.py

    def piechart(request):
        responses_pie =  AnswerRadio.objects.values("body").annotate(Count("id"))
        res = []
        for cat in responses_pie:
            res.append([
                cat["body"],    
                cat["id__count"],
                ])
        return render(request, 'chart_code_v2.html', {'responses_pie_json': json.dumps(res)})
```

reponses_pie_json has 2 keys, body - string values - and id__cout - integer values.
But, in template, I'm not getting how to input response_pie_json in data of HighCharts.
I'm trying to use

```
data: {{ responses_pie_json|safe }}
```

But It just show a blank screen. What should i do?

Comment: How your json looks like ? Do you use numbers inside json or only strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make separate view which send only JSON data. And then get this data with jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('/your/view/url', function(response) {
  // create chart here
});
```

Comment: Why should I make a separate view? Can't I use the view I already have, which already send only JSON data?

Comment: This view don't send JSON data. It render template and pass JSON to template context. this is the wrong approach

Comment: ok, got it. I'm following this example: https://github.com/gnemoug/django_highcharts_demo But I'm getting Uncaught Highcharts error #13 Can you take a look please?